# Test For A Specific Item In Head Slot & Then Activate Something Else

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

**Hi All,** I’m trying to create an addon in MCPE 1.16.2 but I’m struggling to do one thing. I want to be able to detect a player with an item on his head and then follow on with another command like giving him `effects` or a specific item. And when they take it off of their head, the effects/item disappear. There are ways to do it with command blocks like chain and repeat ones but I want to be able to do it all in a function file and I’m kinda new to that; Like does one function file do multiple commands. Like is there a way to do this using an `execute` command. Please Help.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know exactly how to make it with function files (since I can't do the coding on my phone and I don't know how) so what's best is try to use a repeating command block that gives that certain effect for 1 second when you wear that specific hat. The problem lies how to detect the helmet worn using `/execute`.

Comment: Do you know any other commands other than the `/execute` command to detect the helmet as well as following on with that command with like an `/effect` in **only** one repeating command block?

Comment: @MarkGiraffe how would you use `/execute` to do this?

Comment: @Penguin `/execute @a[foo] ~ ~ ~ effect @s foo # #`

Comment: @MarkGiraffe what's the selector tho. Saying `foo` doesn't really tell me anything

Comment: @Penguin Still have no idea. The only things I can remember is using `/replaceitem`. That's not what's to be used.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe I found apps that you can create addons with, which include function files: **Addon Factory** or **Crafty Craft**. Do you have any idea?